# Silex slugs cause 404 page not found

Tags: php, slug, silex

Following the [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html), Silex allows "slugs" to be passed in via the URL for use within your code.

The following example works:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/', function () {
    return 'HAI';
});
```

However, the following gives a 404 Not Found:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/{slug}', function ($slug) {
    return 'HAI' . $slug;
});
```

**How can I fix this 404?**

In case it's of any relevance, here's my Apache Vhost:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/Silex/web"
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory "/var/www/Silex/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

...and my directory structure:

```
/src
  |-- bootstrap.php
/tests
/vendor
/web
  |-- index.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this was an Apache issue. It was assumed that you could either use a .htaccess file, *or* a vhost. You actually need to use **both**.

**.htaccess:**

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

*Note: You can only use FallbackResource if using [Apache 2.2.16 or higher](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html#apache).*

**vhost**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/Silex/web"
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory "/var/www/Silex/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

An alternative is to place the contents of the `.htaccess` file (the `FallbackResource` directive) within the vhost itself, and get rid of the htaccess.

As soon as I added the .htaccess, the slug in my second example worked.

Comment: Pretty sure you can remove `DirectoryIndex index.php` from your vhost config

Comment: Hey @cheesemacfly, if you want to copy this answer and add it for yourself as you discovered it, feel free and I'll award you the upvote & answer :)

Comment: No need, you did the job here! :)